# Symfony2 FOSRestBundle requirements of QueryParam

Tags: rest, symfony

I have the following method with annotation:

```
/**
 * Search on players.
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *   output = "bbb\FrontendBundle\Entity\Player",
 *   statusCodes = {
 *     200 = "Returned when successful",
 *     404 = "Returned when no result was found"
 *   }
 * )
 *
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(name="searchterm", requirements="[a-z]+", nullable=false, description="The term to search about in players.")
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(name="limit", requirements="\d+", default="3", nullable=true, description="How many results to return.")
 *
 * @param Request $request the request object
 * @param $searchterm
 * @param $limit
 * @return array
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException when no result was found
 *
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Route("/search", name="_api_player_search", options={"expose"=true})
 */
public function searchPlayerAction(Request $request, $searchterm, $limit)
{
}
```

The problem is, that if i give for example "Aaron" as searchterm (`api/player/search?searchterm=Aaron`) the variable $searchterm is null. if i try `api/player/search?searchterm=aaron` everything works fine. I guess the problem is the `requirements="[a-z]+"` property of the QueryParam annotation. How can i configure that uppercase charakters are also allowed?

(The same with spaces etc..)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change `requirements="[a-z]+"` to `requirements="[a-zA-Z]+"`

Comment: ok nice, that helps for uppercase charakters. what about spaces for example?
thank you for your answer!

Comment: @humpdi So you could add the space into it, `[a-zA-Z\s]+`

Comment: yeah i found it out, its enough to just add a whitespace, so it looks like `requirements="[a-zA-Z ]+"`